# first time, I get null for csrf_token

Tags: java, spring, csrf

I have a GET method for getting csrf_token. For first time when I call that method received null?

```
@GetMapping("check/mobile/{mobile}/otp/{otp}")
  public Response checkOtp(@PathVariable String mobile, @PathVariable int otp) {
    return otpService.checkOtp(mobile, otp);
  }
```

```
 public Response checkOtp(String mobile, int otp) {
    Response response = new Response();

    response.setStatus(ResponseStatusEnum.SUCCESS);
    response.setDescription(messages.get("otp.success"));
    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(mobile, "",
        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    response.setData(getCsrfToken());

    return response;
  }
```

```
private CsrfToken getCsrfToken() {
    ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
        .currentRequestAttributes();
    HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession();
    return (CsrfToken) session.getAttribute(
        "org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN");
  }
```

Comment: Are you using spring security ...........................

Comment: yes and I want to use csrf. Actually in my app users login via otp (passwordless).